# jqGrid: Number format with decimal point after every two digits

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a column with numbers like 130200000000 which needs to be displayed as 13.02.00.00.00.00 in the jqGrid (a decimal point after every 2 digits).
Can this be done with custom formatter?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try to write something? check here for a start: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function numberDot(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}numberDot(130200000000);
```